# VSCode geddski's Macro Extension: How to write a snippet by simply writting the 3 first letters, and then choose the snippet in the suggestions?

Tags: visual-studio-code, macros

I use https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=geddski.macros to create my macros in Visual Studio Code. My aim is to simply write "pre", then Visual would show me some autocompletion suggestions. Among them, my macro. If I choose the latter, Visual will write my snippet

```
   <pre> 
       var_dump($x); 
   </pre>
```

However I don't know how to do that.

The documentation seems to give an example but I don't understand how it works, it's quite unclear for me:

```
"macros": {
             "doMySnippet": [
                               {
                                  "command": "type", 
                                  "args": {"text": "mySnippetPrefixHere"}
                               },
                               "insertSnippet"
              ] 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put `pre` where `mySnippetPrefixHere` is:

```
"macros": {
  "doMySnippet": [
    {"command": "type", "args": {"text": "pre"}},
    "insertSnippet"
  ]
}
```

and then in a snippets file:

```
"var dump": {
  "prefix": "pre",
  "body": [
    "<pre>\tvar_dump($1);",
    " </pre>"
  ],
  "description": "var dump"
}
```

The macro extension will find your snippet by the prefix. BUT you will have to trigger the macro itself with a keybinding - not just the prefix.  The prefix is only used to find the snippet once you trigger the macro with a keybinding.

---

In your case you don't need to use a macro, just the snippet.  Type <kbd>pre</kbd> and select your `pre` snippet from the list.  The macro would only be if you wanted to insert a snippet together with a series of other commands - but it appears you only want the snippet, no other command.

Comment: Thank you! Good answer! Do you know how to write newlines and tabs indentation in the `body`'s value (but without ending with only one line)? So something looking like this: `"body": [
    "<pre>
   \tvar_dump($1);\n
    </pre>"
  ],` (Stackoverflow doesn't display it, but it doesn't hold on a single line)

Comment: I edited the answer above.  Simply adding a next line is the same as a newline.  And/or you can use `\t` or `\n` within the snippet if you want.  Otherwise I don't understand your question in the comment.  You could edit your question to show exactly how you want the inserted text to look.

Comment: Perfect answer and comment, sorry if I'm not very precise in the question about the look! Thank you!